# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scope.awesomeThings')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, karma-jasmine, yeoman-generator-angular

I got this error every time I run `grunt test` command. I setup a project using `yo angular` and try to run example code given in yeoman's scaffold. I don't what went wrong here, below are code which I tried to test.

**controller/main.js**

```
angular.module('brandPortalApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

**test/controllers/main.js**

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {
  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('brandPortalApp'));
  var MainCtrl,
  scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function () {
    expect(scope.awesomeThings.length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html
// Generated on 2016-05-27 using
// generator-karma 0.8.3

module.exports = function(config) {
  'use strict';

  config.set({
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '../',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: [
      'PhantomJS'
    ],

    // Which plugins to enable
    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine'
    ],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false,

    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // Uncomment the following lines if you are using grunt's server to run the tests
    // proxies: {
    //   '/': 'http://localhost:9000/'
    // },
    // URL root prevent conflicts with the site root
    // urlRoot: '_karma_'
  });
};
```

In Terminal

> Running "connect:test" (connect) task Started connect web server on
>   http://localhost:9001
>
> Running "karma:unit" (karma) task WARN [watcher]: Pattern
>   "/Users/kiwitech/Brand-Portal/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any
>   file. INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at
>   http://localhost:8080/ INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
>   INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket
>   /#NDwIB4AQl7giaVxJAAAA with id 29519679 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X
>   0.0.0) Controller: MainCtrl should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope FAILED
>       forEach@/Users/kiwitech/Brand-Portal/bower_components/angular/angular.js:322:24
>       loadModules@/Users/kiwitech/Brand-Portal/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4548:12
>       createInjector@/Users/kiwitech/Brand-Portal/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4470:30
>       workFn@/Users/kiwitech/Brand-Portal/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2464:60
>       /Users/kiwitech/Brand-Portal/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4588:53
>       TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scope.todos') in /Users/kiwitech/Brand-Portal/test/spec/controllers/main.js (line
>   20)
>       /Users/kiwitech/Brand-Portal/test/spec/controllers/main.js:20:17 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR
>   (0.005 secs / 0.015 secs) Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use
>   --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

I checked other question related to this but those solution not work for this.

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you solved it, but in case you didn't, the issue is with paths in karma.conf.js. I had a similar issue with my angularApp.

As I'm not sure what your architecture is, I made test by myself (pretty much dirty, ie: not optimized), and of course paths should be changed according to the architecture you have.

**jasmineApp folder:**

```
├── app
│   └── scripts
├── bower_components
│   ├── angular
│   ├── angular-animate
│   ├── angular-aria
│   ├── angular-cookies
│   ├── angular-messages
│   ├── angular-mocks
│   ├── angular-resource
│   ├── angular-route
│   ├── angular-sanitize
│   └── angular-touch
└── test
    └── controllers
```

testing file is **test/controllers/main.js**:

```
'use strict';

  // run first test to check karma - I always run this simple test
  // before starting with real tests

  describe('Simple test', function(){
    it("a is in fact 'hello world'", function(){
      var a = "Hello world";
      expect(a).toBe('Hello world');
    });
  });

  describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('brandPortalApp'));

    var MainCtrl,
      scope;

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
      });
    }));

    it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function () {
      expect(scope.awesomeThings.length).toBe(3);
    });
  });
```

controller file is **app/controller/main.js**:

```
angular.module('brandPortalApp',[])
console.log('loaded')
angular.module('brandPortalApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

karma.config.js is something like this:

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html
// Generated on 2016-05-27 using
// generator-karma 0.8.3

module.exports = function(config) {
  'use strict';

  config.set({
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '../',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'jasmineApp/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'jasmineApp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'jasmineApp/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'jasmineApp/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js',
      'jasmineApp/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'jasmineApp/bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
      'jasmineApp/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'jasmineApp/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'jasmineApp/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'jasmineApp/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',

      'jasmineApp/app/scripts/**/*.js',
      //'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'jasmineApp/test/controllers/main.js'
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: [
      'PhantomJS'
    ],

    // Which plugins to enable
    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine'
    ],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false,

    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // Uncomment the following lines if you are using grunt's server to run the tests
    // proxies: {
    //   '/': 'http://localhost:9000/'
    // },
    // URL root prevent conflicts with the site root
    // urlRoot: '_karma_'
  });
};
```

running test the output is OK:

```
21 07 2016 10:58:38.705:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:8080/
21 07 2016 10:58:38.718:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.1.1 server started at http://localhost:8080/
21 07 2016 10:58:38.719:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
21 07 2016 10:58:38.755:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
21 07 2016 10:58:39.017:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#BUObAGDOLqCbC0uRAAAA with id 56816897
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) LOG: 'loaded'

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.006 secs / 0.009 secs)
```

Changing the path for main.js file in karma.config.js 
from working one

```
'jasmineApp/app/scripts/**/*.js',
```

to this

```
'app/scripts/**/*.js', // wrong path
```

the error you got, is back:

```
21 07 2016 11:01:48.645:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/var/www/NODEJS/app/scripts/**/*.js" does not match any file.
21 07 2016 11:01:48.664:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:8080/
21 07 2016 11:01:48.674:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.1.1 server started at http://localhost:8080/
21 07 2016 11:01:48.674:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
21 07 2016 11:01:48.690:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
21 07 2016 11:01:48.955:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#YK-fqsro3-ebMO2kAAAA with id 84208961
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) Controller: MainCtrl should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope FAILED
    forEach@jasmineApp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:321:24
    loadModules@jasmineApp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4592:12
    createInjector@jasmineApp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4514:30
    workFn@jasmineApp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3067:60
    loaded@http://localhost:8080/context.js:151:17
    jasmineApp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4632:53
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scope.awesomeThings') in jasmineApp/test/controllers/main.js (line 20)
    jasmineApp/test/controllers/main.js:20:19
    loaded@http://localhost:8080/context.js:151:17
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.042 secs / 0.007 secs)
```

I hope will help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and I solved it by fixing the path and the list of js files to be called in the karma.conf.js

```
files: [
    'test/libs/jquery.min.js',
    'test/libs/angular.js',
    'test/libs/angular-mocks.js',
    'test/libs/angular-animate.js',
    'test/libs/angular-cookies.js',
    'test/libs/angular-resource.js',
    'test/libs/angular-route.js',
    'test/libs/angular-touch.js',
    'test/libs/angular-sanitize.js',
    'app/scripts/app.js',
    'app/scripts/**/*.js',
    'test/spec/**/*.js'
],
```

Comparing my code with your I feel like maybe calling your app by a direct path (app/scripts/app.js in my case) could help.

Good luck